# Resize element to fit screen size in spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, resize, size

Obviously, you can use UIScreen to find the screen height/width to adjust the scene accordingly, but is there some way I can update all my SKSpriteNodes at once? I made a game with spritekit and only realized afterward, none of it was based on screen size, so it only works well on the iPhone 7 and 8. Is there some shorter code I can do instead of manually changing each size/location to be based on screen size?

Comment: That's not how you create a game with SpriteKit.  Adjust the scene size for different iPhone and iPad models inside your game view controller.

Comment: There are different strategies for adjusting to different screen sizes, aspect ratios, and resolutions.  Apple has some documentation discussing approaches here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/scaling_a_scene_s_content_to_fit_the_view

Comment: @ElTomato My scene is programmed in with just code. Therefore, I can't ajust it inside my Game VC
`//Loads scene
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                
                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I made a SpriteKit Scene in the storyboard and then constrained it to the Safe Area, which allowed aspectFill to work properly.

Comment: All that does is give you black bars on iPhone X devices, usually that is not the preferable experience people are looking for on their X apps.

Comment: Well, for this particular school project, I didn't really have the time to actually set the width, height, and position constraints of my spritenodes to the width and height of the view for each sprite because of how late I noticed this. That was my best quick solution I could find, and noone else had an answer.

Comment: I know, you just set it to the height/width of the SKScene, but I didn't have the time to implement that.

Comment: No, you dont do that either.  Your scene size is static,  like a virtual screen, and your actual screen acts as a camera

Comment: Your aspect fill chops off excess information.  So it sounds to me all you needed to do was design for the X, and let the game crop down to 9x16. Basically, instead of black bars, you have your background gfx

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean

Comment: Your scene size should be a static size, as in 1 resolution only.  It then scales to fit your screen size, preserving the aspect ratio you give it if you choose aspectFill.  Any excess gets “cut off”(it goes beyond viewable screen”) all you needed to do was lengthen your scene size a tiny bit to make it a 18x39 aspect ratio (i believe this changed in iphone 11) and it will work on all devices with no black bars.  It just chops from the top and bottom on 9x16 devices instead of the sides like the way you originally had it.

Comment: I sorta get what you're saying, but how do you fix it code-wise exactly?

Comment: You shouldn’t have to.... just change the size of the sks file

Comment: How would I do that?